# C++ поиск совпадения ключ-значения в map

Tags: c++, map

Вечер добрый! Есть std::map myMap, который я заполнил из file.txt файла(заполнился и отображается корректно)

`1 qwerty
2 sef
3 hhhh`

Далее я от пользователя принимаю значения инт id1 и стринг name1 и хочу их сравнить на совпадение пары в myMap. Если коротко, то у меня не получилось это сделать нормально. Как это сделать корректно?

Comment: Выполните `find` по ключу, если найден - сравните значения.

Comment: `std::map<int,std::string>::iterator it;
  it = myMap.find(id1);`
пробовал так и через find(). когда передаю в параметр name1 выдает ошибку

Comment: `const auto found = myMap.find(name1);`
ошибка

Comment: У вас ключом является int а не  std::string

Comment: Ошибка (активно) E0304 отсутствуют экземпляры перегруженная функция "std::map<_Kty, _Ty, _Pr, _Alloc>::find [с _Kty=int, _Ty=std::string, _Pr=std::less<int>, _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::string>>]", соответствующие списку аргументов ConsoleApplication1 D:\cpp\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.cpp 129

Comment: Ну я не понимаю. почему myMap.find(id1) все ок, а myMap.find(name1) не ок

Comment: @Максим В мапе можно искать только по ключу (по первому из двух типов).

Comment: Маленькая ремарка - find-ом можно искать только по ключу. Если нужен поиск по значению, можно обойти мап циклом и просмотреть все значения. Но это медленнее и для данной задачи не нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если компилятор умеет С++17, то можно одной строкой:

```
bool my_cmp(const std::map<int, std::string>& m,
            const std::pair<int, std::string>& p)  {
    if (auto It = m.find(p.first); It !=  m.end() && It->second == p.second) return true;
    return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool
my_cmp(const std::map<int, std::string>& m,
    const std::pair<int, std::string>& p)
{   
    auto It =m.find(p.first);
    return (It !=  m.end()) && (It->second == p.second);
}
int main() {    
    std::map<int, std::string> Mymap{ {1, "qwerty"} /*...*/};
    std::cout  << std::boolalpha
               << my_cmp(Mymap, { 1, "qwerty" });
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ой, плохо - разыменование, если ключ не найден, ни к чему хорошему не приведет...

Comment: да, слышком коротко

Comment: Что-то я сомневаюсь, что компилятор C++, вычисляя значение выражения (It !=  m.end()) && (It->second == p.second), поймёт, что при ложной левой части правую можно не вычислять. Скорее всего он будет считать в лоб всё выражение. И тут при It, равном m.end(), будет вызвано вот это разыменование итератора It->second. А у итератора m.end() нет поля second. Ведь он указывает не на пару ключ-значение, а ЗА границу контейнера. Будет ошибка.

Comment: @YuryPlinto почему? Вроде простые выражения без перегрузки операторов

Comment: @YuryPlinto https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628526/is-short-circuiting-logical-operators-mandated-and-evaluation-order

Comment: @HolyBlackCat спасибо, буду знать.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге я сделал так: создал ф-ю, которая принимает две инициализированные карты(одна подкачана из файла.тхт и имеет множество пар-ключей "1 qwer, и тд...", вторая же принята от пользователя и содержит одну пару "2 qws"), пробегается по обоим и сравнивает на совпадение пар-ключей. Хз что с оптимизацией, но сравнение проходит четко.

```
void my_cmp(std::map<int, std::string>& r, std::map<int, std::string>& p)
{
    std::map<int, std::string>::iterator i = p.begin(); i != p.end();
    std::map<int, std::string>::iterator ri = r.begin(); ri != r.end();
    int bil = 0;
    for (ri; ri != r.end(); ++ri)
    {
        for (i; i != p.end(); ++i) {
            if ((i->second) == (ri->second) && (i->first) == (ri->first)) {
                if ((i->second) == (ri->second) && (i->first) == (ri->first)) {
                    bil = 1;
                }

            }
        }
    }
    if (bil==1) {
        std::cout << "Entering allowed" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "____________________________" << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Entering not allowed" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "____________________________" << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```